# Remove Image Cache

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, caching, afnetworking

I am using AfNetworking version ~> 1.3.4, which is added by cocoaPods. And I can't upgrade to 2.0 because most of the methods are used in my Application.

AFImageCache (in UIImageView+AFNetworking) cannot be cleared when a new image with the same URL is used

I supposed to add the following method in "UIImageView+AFNetworking" Class for this .

```
+ (void)clearCachedImages {
     [[[self class] af_sharedImageCache] removeAllObjects];
}
```

As because AFNetworking is in my cocoaPods. I am unable to add. 
Please help me how to add this method by category / Subclass?

**EDIT:**

I have tried the following

```
@class AFImageCache;

@interface SPUtility : NSObject
{

}
@end

@implementation SPUtility

+ (void)clearCachedImages {
    [[AFImageCache af_sharedImageCache] removeAllObjects]; //shows following error
}
@end
```

Error: No Known class method for selector 'af_sharedImageCache'
2. Receiver 'AFImageCache' for class message is a forward Declaration

Comment: why are you unable to add. go to pod project and open that file and add this method. What difficulties are you facing

Comment: becoz in future if I update the pod my method will discard. And it will came back to original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a category for `UIImageView` as your `af_sharedImageCache` is in `UIImageView (AFNetworking)`

**SPUtility.m**

```
@interface UIImageView (MyMethods)
+ (NSCache *)af_sharedImageCache;
@end
//you don't have to implement method since it's already defined in UIImageView (AFNetworking)
//It's just for the happiness of the compiler



@implementation SPUtility

+ (void)clearCachedImages {
  [[UIImageView af_sharedImageCache] removeAllObjects];
}
@end
```

Comment: It shows me: "af_sharedImageCache" cannot found. Can plz be specific.

Comment: Yes it will because it's not declared in the header file, so just ignore the warning

Comment: Please check the above Edit part.. @Inder

Comment: yah it works.. Thank you. Thank you so much. I was stuck from morning.

Comment: It's my pleasure :) , remember one thing every method in objective c is public and you can call any method if it exists. :)